# Navigation Bar color doesn't change back? iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have several tableviews with navigation controller.
The navigation bar is white for all the views except the last one, which is red.
I have

`[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];`

in the viewDidLoad of the last tableview and

`[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor];`

in the viewDidLoad of other table views.

It works fine until I get to the last view and the color of the navigation bar changes to red. When I go back to the previous views, all the previous views' navigation bar has changed to red. Where should I put those codes so the color will remain unchanged?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in `viewWillAppear:`. Code in this method will be run every time the view reappear.

Comment: Thanks it worked great! It created another problem of selected cell staying highlighted but fixed it by adding deselectRowAtIndexPath to viewWillAppear :) Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. If your View Controller is a `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`, you *will* have to deselect the row manually in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `viewDidLoad` for initialization purposes only as it is called one time. Adding your code in `viewWillAppear` method should fix your problem as it gets called every time the view appears.

However, I like using the `UIAppearance` to customize the appearance of all instances of a class by creating another method -

```
-(void) setupAppearance {

    UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];

    navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Another method 
    // [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```